# SWFUpload alternatives

Tags: html, flash, file-upload, swfupload

I've developed a system that uses SWFUpload to easily allow the user to upload multiple files with a progress bar showing them the upload progress. It all works fine in my development environment, but is failing for some users in the wild with the Flash movie not loading. I can see the Flash movie is there, if I right click it a window appears saying **Movie not loaded...** (Then on the next line) **About Adobe Flash Player 10...**

So far I've not been able to determine what was causing the failure.

Are there any other alternatives to SWFUpload that will allow for:

- Upload progress bar
- Allow multiple uploads

Alternatively, any ideas on the cause of the SWFUpload issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few:

- http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ (No flash required)
- http://www.uploadify.com/ (jQuery)
- http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/ (mootools)

Comment: The latest version of Uploadify uses SWFUpload, swfobject behind the scene.